# Why is the MATLAB output of this numerical method precision not getting more accurate?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode

Posting here vs math.stackexchange because I think my issue is syntax:

I'm trying to analyze the 2nd order ODE: y'' + 2y' + 2y = e^(-x) * sin(x) using MATLAB code for the midpoint method. I first converted the ODE to a system of 1st order equations and then tried to apply it below, but as the discretizations [m] are increased, the output is stopping at .2718. For example, m=11 yields:

```
ans =

0.2724
```

and m=101:

```
ans =

0.2718
```

and m=10001

```
ans =

0.2718
```

Here's the code:

```
function [y,t] = ODEsolver_midpointND(F,y0,a,b,m)

    if nargin < 5, m = 11; end
    if nargin < 4, a = 0; b = 1; end
    if nargin < 3, a = 0; b = 1; end
    if nargin < 2, error('invalid number of inputs'); end

    t = linspace(a,b,m)';
    h = t(2)-t(1);

    n = length(y0);

    y = zeros(m,n);
    y(1,:) = y0;
    for i=2:m
    Fty = feval(F,t(i-1),y(i-1,:));
    th = t(i-1)+h/2;

    y(i,:) = y(i-1,:) + ...
        h*feval(F,th,y(i-1,:)+(h/2)*Fty );
    end
```

Separate file:

```
function F = Fexample1(t,y)

F1 = y(2);
F2 = exp(-t).*sin(t)-2.*y(2)-2.*y(1);
F = [F1,F2];
```

Third file:

```
[Y,t] = ODEsolver_midpointND('Fexample1',[0 0],0,1,11);
Ye = [(1./2).*exp(-t).*(sin(t)-t.*cos(t)) (1./2).*exp(-t).*((t-1).*sin(t)-  t.*cos(t))];
norm(Y-Ye,inf)
```

Comment: I think that matlab display only four digits but the precision still increase. You can change the output display format with the command `format`. Try to add this line: `format long` before printing the value.

Comment: Thanks. You're right that it is changing a bit, but it's still a lot slower than would be expected. And for m=101 it yields ans = 0.271778245788821, but for m=1001 yields ans = 0.271782072082206 which is larger! So I definitely did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ODE solver looks to me like it should work - however there's a typo in the analytic solution you're comparing to.  It should be

```
Ye = [(1./2).*exp(-t).*(sin(t)-t.*cos(t)) (1./2).*exp(-t).*((t-1).*sin(t)+  t.*cos(t))];
```

i.e. with a `+` sign before the `t.*cos(t)` term in the derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had been looking at it for so long and still hadn't been able to see that.